# Monadic short-circuiting in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'd like to chain a series of `Flow`'s of the form `a -> Try[b]`, where each successive stage handles the `Success` case of the previous, and the `Sink` at the end handles all `Failure` generically.

Can this or something equivalent be encoded succinctly? It's actually a linear flow, but I'm not sure how short of broadcasting and merging at every stage.

Comment: Can't you just map `recover` and flatMap the result? Maybe I'm misunderstanding. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving this is to define a fan-out stage partitioning the `Try` into 2 streams, depending on its outcome

```
  object PartitionTry {
    def apply[T]() = GraphDSL.create[FanOutShape2[Try[T], Throwable, T]]() { implicit builder ⇒
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val success = builder.add(Flow[Try[T]].collect { case Success(a) ⇒ a })
      val failure = builder.add(Flow[Try[T]].collect { case Failure(t) ⇒ t })
      val partition = builder.add(Partition[Try[T]](2, _.fold(_ ⇒ 0, _ ⇒ 1)))

      partition ~> failure
      partition ~> success

      new FanOutShape2[Try[T], Throwable, T](partition.in, failure.out, success.out)
    }
  }
```

Then your generic flow can ingest `Try`s and send the `Failure`s to a sink of choice, whilst passing the `Success`es on

```
  object ErrorHandlingFlow {
    def apply[T, MatErr](errorSink: Sink[Throwable, MatErr]): Flow[Try[T], T, MatErr] = Flow.fromGraph(
      GraphDSL.create(errorSink) { implicit builder ⇒ sink ⇒
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._

        val partition = builder.add(PartitionTry[T]())

        partition.out0 ~> sink

        new FlowShape[Try[T], T](partition.in, partition.out1)
      }
    )
  }
```

usage example below

```
  val source      : Source[String, NotUsed]           = Source(List("1", "2", "hello"))
  val convert     : Flow[String, Try[Int], NotUsed]   = Flow.fromFunction((s: String) ⇒ Try{s.toInt})
  val errorsSink  : Sink[Throwable, Future[Done]]     = Sink.foreach[Throwable](println)
  val handleErrors: Flow[Try[Int], Int, Future[Done]] = ErrorHandlingFlow(errorsSink)

  source.via(convert).via(handleErrors).runForeach(println)
```

Note that

- the 2 stages defined above are reusable for any type (write once, use everywhere)
- this approach can be reused for other type classes - like `Either`, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much!